# Suzuki Access stops running during rains

Tags: suzuki, scooter, air-filter

My Suzuki Access stops running even when there is very little rain or when there is very little water in the roads. Every time when I take it to the mechanic, there is water logged inside the air filter chamber which spoils the air filter and the mechanic asks me to replace it. The mechanic claims that this is the case with all the scooters. Is it true?

It has been 18 months since I bought it and I had to struggle in the roads every time it rained. Does this happen in bikes too? Because I am fed up with my access and planning to buy Honda Unicorn now. Any advice is much appreciated.

**Edit:**

I will explain in detail what happens exactly when I drive while it is raining, as requested by Dan. When I apply brakes and start accelerating again, the acceleration is not smooth and I experience air blocks. After that it doesn't matter how hard I accelerate, the engine fails to respond and I feel severe air blocks thereafter. Within a few minutes of struggle the engine comes to a total halt. And the next morning when I take it to the mechanic, the air filter chamber is full of water and costs me Rs.170 every time this happens.

Comment: Rain causing issues is certainly a common problem, but it's not one you have to live with. That said, it's all but impossible to diagnose without a lot more detail as we need to define "stops running". Your mechanics theory doesn't sound too out there, but it could also easily be an electrical issue.

Comment: I can't edit my comment, but if the issue is the Air Filter then you should look at why the intake isn't waterproof.

Comment: You need to contact the service station. I am using Access from last 1 year and facing no dificulties.

Comment: When I contacted the service station, they claim that this is the case with all the scooters like Suzuki Access, Honda Activa etc.

Comment: @vivek   Can you explain what an 'air block' is from your post?

Answer (score 2):

The stock tuning of the carburetor is meant to and should work in almost any weather conditions. There's obviously a change in the temperature and the humidity while its raining. And its because of the improper tuning AFR (air to fuel ratio) of the carb, it causes a "missing" (a vernacular term we have in India) and eventually your scooter going of while its raining. When its humid, lots cold/humid air would enter your engine chamber while the existing fuel input is less.

follow [this](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100425211040AAWXD12) link to read about lean fuel mixture. This is not really a case of lean fuel mixture but you might get the basic idea.

Now how to resolve this problem, take it to any local mechanic and tell them your problem. Tell then that the bike goes of in the rain and that you need to adjust the carb or slightly raise the "slow-speed".  10 mins of work and you'll be fine.

Ride Safe.

Answer (score 0):

I have been owning it since last 5 years and this is a problem I face every year. But once I take it to the service center they cover the air filter with a plastic cover and that solves my problem for the rest of the season.

Comment: Is it good enough for an answer or more of a comment?

Comment: It's a wordaround, which qualifies as an answer IMHO.

Answer (score -2):

I am using Access form 14 months. I am not facing any problem with it. Some vehicles may contain Manufacture defects. So it is better to take to SHOW ROOM not to a UNAUTHORIZED  mechanic

Comment: Couldn't disagree more - unless it's under warranty, main dealers / showrooms exist almost solely to charge you lots of money. Take it to a trusted, local, mechanic who knows the scooter well.

Comment: If you can demonstrate that the dealer has some type of equipment or tool not available to independent mechanics, please share that information. Otherwise you are missing the point of this site. Literally every question could be answered "take it to the Dealer" which would be pointless.